# scrape specific data from td tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have to **scrape** this data

- The name of the company that is hiring
- The location of the company
- The position that the ad is for

This is the website that I want to scrape from [link](https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs%60). I was able to get td data but I need to start from a specific td tag (i.e start from this tr tag)

```
<tr style="height:14px"></tr>
        <tr class='athing' id='20463814'>
  <td align="right" valign="top" class="title"><span class="rank"></span></td>      <td></td><td class="title"><a href="https://mino-games.workable.com/j/69BCF95C8F" class="storylink" rel="nofollow">Mino Games (YC W11) Is Hiring Game Developers in Montreal</a><span class="sitebit comhead"> (<a href="from?site=workable.com"><span class="sitestr">workable.com</span></a>)</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td><td class="subtext">
    <span class="age"><a href="item?id=20463814">11 hours ago</a></span>      </td></tr>
```

and then keep on moving towards other tags and at the same time keep getting the data of company name, location and position in a separate variable. I know it's a lot to ask for but I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

this is what I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs'

plain_html_text = requests.get(url);

soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.text, "html.parser")

table_body = soup.find('tbody')
rows = soup.find('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print (cols)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @abdusco edited my question and added my code that i tried

Comment: Do you have experience with NLP? Because extracting entities and proper names from a natural language text is, although somewhat possible with regular expressions, not a trivial task.

Comment: @abdusco no i do not have any experience with NLP. I just need a simple python code that can get the test from these td tags and then first indexed values get used as company name while for location the words coming after 'in' get sent into the lcoation variable. For position the remaining text in between can be added. I do not want to make it that much complicated

Comment: Not every line is formatted the same.

Comment: do you want only scrape this link `Mino Games (YC W11) Is Hiring Game Developers in Montreal` link?

Comment: @abdusco yes you are right, but first indexed values are all company names in the whole page, and many lines do not included location while those that include location are using the word 'in' and then location is written, I would settle with location as null for lines that do not include any location at all

Comment: @KunduK like this `Company_Name = Mino Games`, `Position = Is Hiring Game Developers`, `Location = Montreal`

Comment: @ahsannissar : so you want to get data from `Mino Games (YC W11) Is Hiring Game Developers in Montreal` link only not any other links?

Comment: @KunduK i want from all. Like in a loop. Since my goal is to later save them in mysqldb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not easy problem, but this script could get you started:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs'

plain_html_text = requests.get(url);

soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.text, "html.parser")

rows = []
for title in soup.select('.title:not(:has(.morelink)) .storylink'):
    t = title.get_text(strip=True)

    company = re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?:is hiring|is looking|seeking|hiring)', t, flags=re.I)
    if company:
        company = company[0].strip()
    else:
        company = '-'

    position = re.findall(r'(?:is hiring|is looking|seeking|hiring)(.*?)(?=\bin\b|$)', t, flags=re.I)
    if position:
        position = position[0].strip()
    else:
        position = '-'

    location = re.findall(r'(?:\bin\b)(.*)', t, flags=re.I)
    if location:
        location = location[0].strip()
    else:
        location = '-'

    rows.append([company, position, location])

print('{: ^50}{: ^80}{: ^20}'.format('Company', 'Position', 'Location'))
for row in rows:
    c, p, l = row
    print('{: <50}{: <80}{: <20}'.format(c, p, l))
```

Prints:

```
                     Company                                                          Position                                          Location      
Scale AI                                          engineers to accelerate the development of AI                                   -                   
Mino Games (YC W11)                               Game Developers                                                                 Montreal            
BuildZoom (YC W13)                                – Help us un-break construction                                                 -                   
Bitmovin (YC S15)                                 a Video Solutions Architect/Software Engineer                                   Brazil              
Streak – CRM for Gmail (YC S11)                                                                                                   Vancouver           
ZeroCater (YC W11)                                a Director of Engineer                                                          SF                  
UpCodes (YC S17)                                  engineers to automate compliance for architects                                 -                   
Tech Nonprofit Upsolve (YC W19)                   a Software Engineer                                                             -                   
Gitlab (YC W15)                                   an Engineering Manager, Ecosystem                                               -                   
Saleswhale (YC S16)                               Our First U.S. Strategic Account Executive                                      -                   
Jerry (YC S17)                                    for a Director of Ops and Growth                                                -                   
Sourceress (YC S17)                               Product and ML Engineers (Remote OK, No Prior ML OK)                            -                   
GiveCampus (YC S15)                               a Product Designer who cares about education                                    -                   
Iris Automation                                   an Account Executive for B2B Flying Vehicle Software                            -                   
LogDNA (YC W15)                                   Software Engineers – DevOps Monitoring at Scale                                 -                   
Flexport                                          software engineers to work on our trucking apps                                 Chicago             
Mux                                               an ML engineer to help train our machines to deliver better video               -                   
The Muse (YC W12)                                 a Product Director for Growth                                                   -                   
OneSignal                                         an SRE to scale our bare-metal infrastructure                                   -                   
Atomwise (YC W15)                                 a Senior Systems/Cloud Engineer                                                 -                   
Demodesk (YC W19)                                 Software Engineers                                                              Munich              
Gusto                                             for Android and iOS developers to build our native mobile app                   -                   
Fond (YC W12)                                     an Engineering Manager                                                          Portland            
ReadMe (YC W15)                                   – Help us make APIs easy to use                                                 -                   
Keeper (YC W19)                                   a lead engineer – help save gig workers money on taxes                          -                   
Asseta (YC S13)                                   a technical lead                                                                -                   
Tesorio (YC S15)                                  Engineering Managers, Senior Engineers                                          -                   
Standard Cognition (YC S17)                       – Work on vision systems                                                        Rust                
Curebase (YC S18)                                 first sales hire – distributed clinical research                                -                   
Mashgin (YC W15)                                  a Fullstack SWE Interested                                                      Computer Vision/AI
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic scraper that splits titles into company and position.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

from pprint import pprint

def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})
    res.raise_for_status()
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_jobs(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    titles = soup.select('.storylink')
    hiring_re = re.compile('\s+(is)?\s+(hiring|seeking|looking)\s+(for)?', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    jobs = []
    for el in titles:
        title = el.text.strip()
        m = hiring_re.search(title)
        if not m:
            continue
        company = title[:m.start()].strip()
        offer = title[m.end():].strip().title()
        jobs.append({
            'company': company,
            'wants': offer,
        })
    return jobs


url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs'
soup = make_soup(url)
jobs = extract_jobs(soup)
pprint(jobs)
```

output:

```
 {'company': 'Mino Games (YC W11)', 'wants': 'Game Developers In Montreal'},
 {'company': 'BuildZoom (YC W13)', 'wants': '– Help Us Un-Break Construction'},
 {'company': 'Streak – CRM for Gmail (YC S11)', 'wants': 'In Vancouver'},
 {'company': 'ZeroCater (YC W11)', 'wants': 'A Director Of Engineer In Sf'},
 {'company': 'UpCodes (YC S17)', 'wants': 'Engineers To Automate Compliance For Architects'},
 {'company': 'Tech Nonprofit Upsolve (YC W19)', 'wants': 'A Software Engineer'},
...
```

Comment: This is awesome :) Thanks